# Please add/suggest a tag wiki when creating a tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

If you've created a tag, please add or suggest a description for it.

If you don't know what the tag's about, who will? If you aren't interested in the tag, who else would be?

It doesn't have to be brilliant prose, just get it started.

This is especially useful when a tag could be ambiguous, such as [fukushima](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fukushima).

Comment: Well I just made a tag for Fukushima in fact. Since it's not that famous for tourism I made a definition tag and it should cover both the prefecture and the city which is its capital. We can disambiguate at such time that we have questions about other Fukushimas.

Comment: Related, on the network meta site: [Can we get people to fill in tag wikis when they create a new tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267939) which points to [Promote tag wiki creation for new tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129624). One big point from there: "tag wikis aren't particularly useful for the vast majority of tags." The ideas proposed there turned out to be too complicated, resulting in [this feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233897/) instead; unfortunately, it doesn't help you. All of which leads me to ask, how severe is your tag confusion problem in practice?

Answer (score 3):

I am aware others disagree but I agree. IMO more important to reduce the risk of, for example, [mco](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mco) (presently only applied to questions about Orlando) being applied also to ones about [Miscellaneous Charges Orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_charges_order) than it is to be concerned about the exact wording of a Usage guide. The latter may be edited at any time for a 'fix' that applies 'across the board'. Jumbling *Orlando* with *Miscellaneous Charges Orders* would require a post by post review to 'unscramble'.

[mco](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mco) is far from unique in the possibility of ambiguity. [tsa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsa) is presently applied to *Transportation Security Administration* but, without a Usage guide, for consistency of usage with other IATA codes might just as, or more, easily have been taken to refer to *Taipei Songshan Airport*.

And there is a swathe of others such as: [goa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goa) - Presently the Usage guide includes is *A small state in India* but there is also *Genoa Cristoforo Colombo Airport* (IATA GOA) and possibilities for ambiguity with `Cambridge`, `Plymouth`, `Wellington` ...

See (!) also [Tag sea is used for Seattle-Tacoma International Airport and for Seas (ie big salty waters)](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/tag-sea-is-used-for-seattle-tacoma-international-airport-and-for-seas-ie-big-sa).

[ana](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ana) is not meant for Angama Mara Airport.
[art](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art) is not meant for Watertown International Airport.
[vfs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vfs) is not meant for Vision Flight Center though that is its ICAO code.
[iata](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iata) is not meant for the Illinois Art Therapy Association.