# Tag sea is used for Seattle-Tacoma International Airport and for Seas (ie big salty waters)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have tried to make a new tag for seas, as the first question I found was not about travel on sea but on a coastal feature.

Is there an alternative tag we can use for the watery features, or is there an option to change the airport tag into "SEA" and make a second one "sea" or "seas" to distinguis them.

I do not feel that "oceans" would be an useful alternative as many seas do not qualify for oceans.

Edit after seeing the first answer:
Would it be a good thing to add an 'airport tag identifier' to the airport tags, as we can not make them capitals?

Comment: it would be good if all the airport tags are upper case. Another meta thread on this here: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126/standardizing-on-airport-tags

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not add a suffix? for example, [lax-airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lax-airport) and [cdg-airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cdg-airport). Just like what we did with citizens tags.

Comment: I like this suggestion and it doesn’t require recoding anything of the SE code =D

Comment: Nice idea, but I foresee a slight problem possibly. When you type "air" into the tagging box, it's going to expand to a 1000 tags which might interfere with choosing the intentional tag of airport or airline or whatever.

Comment: @Berwyn not at all, SE will pick up the top 6 tags that matched the entered characters, ordered by popularity.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Ok. Sounds good then.

Comment: I like this suggestion and think it is very well workable.

Answer (score 7):

Network-wide, and written in the [help centre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> When creating your new tag bear in mind that tags …
>
> - must be shorter than 25 characters
> - must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

Uppercase letters in tags are, unfortunately, not possible because of the restrictions SE places on them. I don’t think that the airport codes here and the few other occasions will be enough to change that policy.

If your question was about costal features, maybe [seaside](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seaside) could do the trick?

Comment: Thanks. I will wait a bit longer for other suggestions but it is certainly an option.

Comment: Berwyn linked to [this meta thread](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126/standardizing-on-airport-tags) above where both Jeff & Joel seem to be pro making it easier to read these tags - Joel even specifically mentions uppercase. I know it's an old post, but if it has Jeff & Joel behind it.... maybe we _could_ post a feature request and see if it could happen? Uppercase airport tags definitely would make more sense

Answer (score 3):

Just posted as a comment but it's also an answer. Rename the airport tag to seatac or seatac-airport if you want. We locals call it SeaTac anyway.

Comment: That would work for SeaTac but would become a bit unwieldy for airports like CDG or ORD, etc., unless it would only apply to airports that conflict with other tags or are ambiguous.

Comment: @Berwyn Well, I thought that was the problem we were solving was this unique case, not the more generaI one. don't believe his edit was posted by the time I posted my answer. Personally, I think adding `-airport` to every single airport tag is an overkill solution to this one exception, but that's why we've got Meta, I guess.

Comment: While I agree that everyone calls it SeaTac (even the city in which the airport itself resides is officially named "SeaTac",) it's probably best to keep the airport tags uniform as their IATA codes (or perhaps ICAO/FAA/etc. codes on the off chance we get a question for an airport that doesn't have an IATA code.)

Comment: Sea(tac)? Maybe

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making [sea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea) a synonym of some other tag ([ocean](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocean) perhaps?) as well as renaming the airport tag to [sea-airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-airport), so you don't have people mistagging Seattle-Tacoma as Sea.

Answer (score 0):

Add on a picture of a sea, or use the  emoji, as a visual display for the [sea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea) tag, for extra disambiguation.